# Read CSV row and map to class with collection of subclass

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I am reading in a CSV file.
There are no headers.
I need to map it to a class which has a collection of sub objects.
I know the amount of objects in the collection.

```
Public Class Foo{
public int id {get; set;}
public Bar[] bars {get; set;}
public class Bar{
public int id {get; set;}
public string str {get; set;}
}
}
```

I am trying to accomplish this using CSVHelper
I have tried creating a mapper like below.
However I just get the following error:
CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException: 'The conversion cannot be performed.

```
   public sealed class Mapper : ClassMap<Foo>
        {
            public Mapper()
            {
                Map(m => m.id).Index(0);
                Map(m => m.bars).Index(1, 2);
            }
        }
```

It seems the Index overload with 2 parameters is expecting to just convert collections of values as opposed to objects constructed from multiple columns.

My actual code has a collection size of 80, with objects with 5 fields on them so bringing them out onto the base Foo object is not ideal.

I know I can pull out the CSV as a string and string split by lines and commas and iterate through them manually but using a proper CSV library seemed cleaner and less prone to oversights.

I see there is also the option to add a References with a map to it

```
 References<BarMap>(m => m.Bars);

public sealed class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
        {
            public BarMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.id).Index(0);
                Map(m => m.str).Index(1);
            }
        }
```

But I cannot see how I can appropriately set the Indexes for it.
The reference does not allow specifying an index.

Comment: Maybe CsvH can do it, but I've only ever done that kind of thing manually; use CsvH to read the file to a collection of class then use LINQ to reshape. Can you post more details so we can see?

Comment: (What does the csv file look like?)

Comment: if the csv file were to contain 1 foo with 1 bar then it would be "1,1,my string"

Comment: I was more interested to know what it looks like if it eg had 2 foo each with 3 bar - 6 rows of 3 columns or 2 rows of 7 columns?

Comment: There is usually going to be just 1 foo, but there can be more. Every foo is going to have 80 bars. so it will be more like "1,1,mystring,1,otherstring,1,thirdstring,1,anotherstring " etc

Comment: So if a foo has an ID and 80 Bars and a Bar has 2 properties it means every row in your csv file has 161 columns? 1 foo ID plus (80 bars * 2 properties per bar) `1+(80*2) == 161` ?

Comment: And there will never be any two rows that have the same foo id?

Comment: yes there would be 161 columns. There may be duplicate foo ids but that is irrelevant each row must translate to its own independent foo class.

Comment: Can you paste the complete, exact headers line into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `Convert` in your mapping to get the `bars`.  I assumed two `Bar` records, but you can change the `for` loop to account for different numbers of `Bar`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var input = "1,1,Dolor,2,Lorem\n2,3,Sit,4,Ipsum";

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
    };

    using (var reader = new StringReader(input))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<Mapper>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();       
    }
}

public sealed class Mapper : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public Mapper()
    {
        Map(m => m.id).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.bars).Convert(args =>
        {
            var bars = new List<Bar>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i += 2)
            {
                var bar = new Bar 
                { 
                    id = args.Row.GetField<int>(i), 
                    str = args.Row.GetField<string>(i + 1)
                };

                bars.Add(bar);
            }

            return bars.ToArray();
        });
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Bar[] bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to automatically map the file to your class, but I've achieved the required result using a [DTO class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).
Considering the data is:

```
0,0,0,Lorem 
1,0,1,Ipsum
2,1,0,Dolor
3,1,1,Sit
4,1,2,Amet
```

Running the following code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
    };

    IEnumerable<FoobarDto> records = null;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader("file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FoobarDtoMap>();
        records = csv.GetRecords<FoobarDto>().ToList();
    }

    var finalRecords = records.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => new Foo { Id = x.Key, Bars = x.Select(f => f.Bar).ToArray() });
}

public class FoobarDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Foo.Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Bar[] Bars { get; set; }
    public class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }
}

public sealed class FoobarDtoMap : ClassMap<FoobarDto>
{
    public FoobarDtoMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Bar.Id).Index(2);
        Map(m => m.Bar.Str).Index(3);
    }
}
```

It gives you the proper result.
Please note that there should be a unique column at index 0 for `CsvHelper` to correctly parse every line of the csv file.

Comment: In your "example data" is the first column actually the line number?

Comment: @CaiusJard In my example data, yes it could be. But as I get it, `CsvHelper` needs the first column to be unique in order to consider all the lines in mapping. So first column can contain any random values as long as they are unique. If you delete the first column, the `finalRecords` variable will only contain two elements instead of five.